Почему С++ медленнее С
Почему говорят, что С++ медленнее С?
Даже если код одинаковый?
Объясните пожалуйста

Почему вы так решили? Кто говорит?

@SwaD Слышал на ютубе, от дедов на форумах и т.п. От того и вопросы ибо я им не верю особо...

Ну, как в том анекдоте — "состояние вашей гортани и голосовых связок не мешает вам говорить то же самое". Ну, или противоположное :)

Если код одинаковый, то и скорость будет одинаковая.

@HolyBlackCat, ну, что вы в самом деле - начнем с того, что есть разные опции компиляции, и, в общем случае, можно получить совершенно разный результат, имея один и тот же исходный код, просто даже на разных компиляторах при настройках по умолчанию. Если бы вы сказали, что транслированный (скомпилированный) код будет одинаковым - тут вопросов нет.

@AlexanderSt Конечно, я имею в виду при прочем равном - тот же компилятор с теми же настройками. "Если бы вы сказали, что транслированный (скомпилированный) код будет одинаковым" - вот это не понял. Это так же зависит от выбора компилятора и флагов.

Если код написан на С, то программист с прямыми руками получит одинаковую скорость на С и С++ компиляторах. С другой стороны, С++ компилятор умеет оптимизировать так как C не умеет. Хороший пример: qsort в C против std::sort в С++. Ни при каких обстоятельствах qsort не обгонит std::sort. И почти всегда будет отставать. Чтобы выровнять ситуацию, программисту на С придётся писать сортировку заново для каждого места, где вызывается qsort.

@StanislavVolodarskiy , хм, как бы, зачем каждый раз заново? В заголовочный файл static inline qsort(), а в программе static inline compar(), и вуаля. Хотя стратегия размножения кода (template, inline), часто вредит кэшированию онного и приводит к обратному эффекту. А вот массив нужного размера на стеке выделить, или restrict имитировать, так ведь в чистом C++ не выйдет же. ;)

@Serge3leo, для каждого типа записи нужна своя сортировка. Если вы сортируете целые, передача указателя в функцию - уже проблема. Получается что в C не сделать универсальный прототип компаратора. Так что будет требоваться много версий.

В C практически все в языке сделано с упором на скорость и память.
Другое дело — C++. В нем все также можно писать как в C, но для высокоуровневой разработки были введены разного рода "расширения" — ООП (которое уже ведет к замедлению работы программы), небесплатные STL-контейнеры, умные указатели, даже std::cout вместо printf ведёт к падению скорости работы и увеличению используемой памяти.
Как то так, обобщенно.

Иногда cout (да и вообще templates) быстрее, но в целом вы правы. Хотя, основная причина не в самом языке (тут я имею в виду результат компиляции базовых констукций), а в программистах  (точнее в тех, кто их учит ...), навыки которых нарабатываются абстракциями, предоставляемыми языком

@avp C++ все больше идет в сторону высокоуровневой разработки, но C с его memcpy, strcat и сырыми указателями никуда не делся. И действительно, скорость работы программы зависит от уровня навыков разработчика, решающего, где и как эффективно использовать абстракции вроде того же STL (и стоит ли брать List, когда нужен только доступ по индексу).

Я бы к этому еще добавил, что С++ слишком сложен для того, чтобы "массовый программист" смог писать на нем эффективный код (речь не о студенческих работах)

@MS.msuic9, я бы сказал - в С практически всё в языке сделано с упором на то, что программирующий отчетливо понимает, что он делает, какими средствами и что он хочет достичь в результате, а скорость и память тут вещи сопутствующие

Это видимо еще одно "Слышал на ютубе, от дедов на форумах и т.п.". ООП - это не расширение, а методология с подход описанию сущностей предметной области. Активно используется и в С и сам по себе ничего не замедляет. "STL-контейнеры, умные указатели" - С из коробки не предлагает для них альтернатив по большей части, а написать на коленке вариант хотя бы приближающийся к эффективности и универсальности сможет далеко не каждый. Самопальные велосипеды - бич С. Так что обычно и STL-контейнеры и умные указатели приводят как раз к увеличению скорости и снижению потребления памяти.

@user7860670 Я специально взял в кавычки слово "расширение" — как по мне слово, которое понимает любой человек. STL контейнеры, действительно, быстрее некачественных велосипедных векторов на C, но программистам на нем обычно и не приходиться работать с list-ами. Все что нужно, можно реализовать через realloc. А вот умные указатели как раз приводят к увеличению потребляемой памяти (и, судя по проверкам на null, в скорости тоже). Так что в задачах, где можно почти без боли использовать C, все высокоуровневые абстракции C++ только понизят производительность.
